# Jenkin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy command stopped executing deploy goal

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, maven-plugin, jenkins-groovy

We are using Jenkins to build our project and command "**-U clean org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy**" was working earlier and resulting in
maven/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/home/jenkins/jobs/`jobName`/workspace/.repository -U clean deploy

but due to recent changes I am seeing jenkin console not converting org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy to deploy life cycle
maven/apache-maven-3.9.4/bin/mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/usr/local/csapps/jenkins/jobs/`jobName`/workspace/.repository -U clean org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy

Due to this our jenkin builds are failing with error **Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy (default-cli) on project `jobName`: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact**

I tried to change maven version while building the project but still not sure why all the projects are failing to build. I know I can modify the project configurations to replace org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy with deploy but there are multiple jobs and we want to avoid making those changes without finding out root cause and is there an alternate solution which can help avoid modifying multiple projects.